# What's the easiest way to allow Exchange 2003 remote (no MSO client) users check their Mailbox size?

Tags: exchange-2003, outlook-web-app, webmail

We are migrating from Exchange 2003 with no quota settings to Exchange 2010 with limited mailbox sizes. We are trying to get users to clean their mailboxes prior to the move to reduce the transfer load, as well as to comply with new quotas on the 2010 system.

But many users access their mail through webmail only. I cannot see a way for users to access their mail store size in this manner.

Has anyone else run into this problem? Is there a good way to easily let users check their own mailbox size? The only thing I've come up with as a workaround is a report that IT generates and mail-merge it out to users daily with their current mailbox size. This is cumbersome and time consuming compared to a way for them to check their own mailbox size however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is you can't. There is no native functionality in OWA in Exchange 2003 to display mailbox sizes.

You could look at setting quotas to something low and setting it for warn only which would notify users that they are over quota but not limit them otherwise.

You could also script your existing workaround to export users and mail them and have it run automatically as a task.

You could also create a custom ASP page and drop it into your front-end (exchweb\bin) that checks the mailboxsize and displays it to the user (for example: http://www.jeffsheen.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=30). There are some security drawbacks with the example provided which he notes at the bottom of the article.

Comment: We chose to set a soft quota on the old system to match the hard quota on the new one; this was an excellent suggestion, thank you.